# How to apply rounded corners and drop shadows to a table with borders?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Shadows do seem to work, but only if you use some really big shadow. You can't use a small one. Does anyone know why this is?

When it comes to rounded corners, it feels almost impossible to do it with a border around the table.

Here is what I have;
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJwyrW

```
<div class="flex flex-row items-center min-h-screen">
  <table class="w-full max-w-xl mx-auto bg-grey-lightest border border-grey shadow-sm">
  <thead class="text-left bg-grey-light border-b-2 border-grey">
    <tr>
      <th class="p-4">Name</th>
      <th class="p-4">Email</th>
      <th class="p-4">Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="p-4">James</td>
      <td class="p-4">James@example.com</td>
      <td class="p-4">United States</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="p-4">Martin</td>
      <td class="p-4">Martin@example.com</td>
      <td class="p-4">United Kingdom</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="p-4">Jeff</td>
      <td class="p-4">Jeff@example.com</td>
      <td class="p-4">Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need `border-collapse: separate` for border radius to work

Comment: Here's an update of your codepen, border + shadow: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOegyK

Comment: And btw, if you need `border-collapse: collapse` for some other reason, set border (and shadow) on the table's `div` parent.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks this fixed it! Although it is a little buggy with the shadow. It gets cut off because of `overflow: hidden`. Is there anyway to fix this? I fixed it by applying some y-axis margin. But I feel this is a dodgy way of fixing it.

Comment: If the parent of the shadow element has `overflow: hidden`, you need to create a margin, or else it gets cutted off